# Import contingency table (.csv-format) as "table" rather than "data.frame" in R

Tags: r, csv, data-management

I am working with the (I think) very cool **titanic data** that is publicly available.

There are two principal ways of how to import it to R:

(1) You can either use the *built-in dataset* `Titanic` (`library(datasets)`) or

(2) you can download it as *.csv-file*, e.g. [here](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/datasets.html).

Now, the data is aggregated frequency data. I would like to convert the **multi-dimensional contingency table** into an **individual-level data frame**.

**PROBLEM:** If I use the built-in dataset, this is no problem; if I use the imported .csv-file, however, it doesn't work. This is the error message I get:

> Error in rep(1:nrow(tablevars), counts) : invalid 'times' argument In
>   addition: Warning message: In expand.table(Titanic.table) : NAs
>   introduced by coercion

*Why? And what do I wrong?* Many thanks.

**R CODE**

```
#required packages
library(datasets)
library(epitools)

#(1) Expansion of built-in data set
data(Titanic)    
Titanic.raw <- Titanic
class(Titanic.raw) # data is stored as "table"
Titanic.expand <- expand.table(Titanic.raw)

#(2) Expansion of imported data set
Titanic.raw <- read.table("Titanic.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=1)
class(Titanic.raw) #data is stored as "data.frame"

Titanic.table <- as.table(as.matrix(Titanic.raw)) 
class(Titanic.table) #data is stored as "table"

Titanic.expand <- expand.table(Titanic.table)
```

Comment: As soon as you wrapped as.matrix() around a dataframe, you turned it into a character valued matrix. Almost certainly not what you wanted ... although it remains unclear what you do want.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to convert aggregated frequency data into individual-level data, i.e. create a dataset with an observation for each unit (I need such an expanded dataset for further analysis). I know how to do it with the built-in dataset (No. 1) but not with the imported dataset (No. 2) - and I would really like to learn it. Therefore, may I ask how you would do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TiF That sounds like a separate question...but `do.call(rbind,rep(split(tita[,2:5],1:nrow(tita)),tita[,6]))->repped` where tita is the data.frame version that is read in, with X in col 1, Freq in col 6.

Comment: @Frank. Thanks for this. It is certainly true that you can answer to the original question (how to expand the dataset) in many different ways. But DWin was perfectly right in assuming that I wanted to find a way that allows me to use the expand.table() function ... Sorry for the confusion and many thanks for your solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want `xtabs`: Watch out that the factor coding is different for the factors in the `Titanic` and the `Titanic.new` objects. By default factor levels have lexicographic order, while two of the `Titanic` factors do not :

```
 str(Titanic)
 table [1:4, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 0 0 35 0 0 0 17 0 118 154 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Class   : chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
  ..$ Sex     : chr [1:2] "Male" "Female"
  ..$ Age     : chr [1:2] "Child" "Adult"
  ..$ Survived: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"

 Titanic.raw <- read.table("~/Downloads/Titanic.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", row.names=1)

 str( Titanic.new <- 
               xtabs( Freq ~ Class + Sex + Age +Survived, data=Titanic.raw))

 xtabs [1:4, 1:2, 1:2, 1:2] 4 13 89 3 118 154 387 670 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 4
  ..$ Class   : chr [1:4] "1st" "2nd" "3rd" "Crew"
  ..$ Sex     : chr [1:2] "Female" "Male"
  ..$ Age     : chr [1:2] "Adult" "Child"
  ..$ Survived: chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xtabs" "table"
 - attr(*, "call")= language xtabs(formula = Freq ~ Class + Sex + Age + Survived, data = Titanic.raw)
```

An 'xtabs'-object inherits from 'table'-class so you can use that `expand.table` function.

Comment: Many thanks! It works ... and I learnt a new way of how to use xtabs() :-)